# Is there any options in yocto bitbake to make the command autocomplete?

Tags: yocto

Is there any options in yocto bitbake to make the command autocomplete?

For example

```
bitbake busybox -c <tab> should display the available tasks for that particular receipe
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take use this repo - https://github.com/lukaszgard/bitbake-completion, which store bash completion scripts that allows to complete recipes and all subcommands for *bitbake* and other tools (like *devtool* and *bitbake-layer*). I am author of this repository so in case of any problem please let me know.

Comment: This just works with sumo and thud? Do you support just two version? Does it work with rocko version? thanks

Comment: Full support is for **sumo** and **thud** branches (please look at available branches on github), there is a goal to support other branches and for *zsh* completion but I don't know when I will have a chance to make it.

Comment: Have you considered merging it back to the forked one ?